# What am I doing wrong while importing the following data into sas

Tags: import, sas

I am trying to import certain data into my SAS datset using this piece of code:

Data Names_And_More;

```
Infile 'C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Torrent Downloads\SAS 9.1.3 Portable\Names_and_More.txt';
Input Name   &  $20. 
      Phone  :  $20.  
      Height &  $10.  
      Mixed  &  $10.;
run;
```

The data in the file is as below:

```
Roger Cody (908)782-1234 5ft. 10in. 50 1/8
Thomas Jefferson (315)848-8484 6ft. 1in. 23 1/2
Marco Polo (800)123-4567 5Ft. 6in. 40
Brian Watson (518)355-1766 5ft. 10in 89 3/4
Michael DeMarco (445)232-2233 6ft. 76 1/3
```

I have been trying to learn SAS and while going through Ron Cody's book Learning SAS by example,I found to import the kind of data above, we can use 'the ampersand (&) informat modifier. The ampersand, like the colon,says to use the supplied informat, but the delimiter is now two or more blanks instead of just one.' (Ron's words, not mine). However, while importing this the result (dataset) is as follows:

```
                          Name            Phone      Height        Mixed

                  Roger Cody (908)782-    Thomas    Jefferson    Marco Polo
```

Also, for further details the SAS log is as follows:

> 419  Data Names_And_More;
>   420  Infile 'C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Torrent Downloads\SAS 9.1.3 Portable\Names_and_More.txt';
>   421  Input Name   &  $20.
>   422        Phone  :  $20.
>   423        Height &  $10.
>   424        Mixed  &  $10.
>   425  ;run;

NOTE:

> The infile 'C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Torrent Downloads\SAS 9.1.3 Portable\Names_and_More.txt' is:
>         File Name=C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Torrent Downloads\SAS 9.1.3 Portable\Names_and_More.txt,
>         RECFM=V,LRECL=256

NOTE:

> LOST CARD.
>   Name=Brian Watson (518)35 Phone=Michael Height=DeMarco (4 Mixed=  *ERROR*=1 *N*=2
>   NOTE: 5 records were read from the infile 'C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Torrent Downloads\SAS 9.1.3
>         Portable\Names_and_More.txt'.
>         The minimum record length was 37.
>         The maximum record length was 47.
>   NOTE: SAS went to a new line when INPUT statement reached past the end of a line.
>   NOTE: The data set WORK.NAMES_AND_MORE has 1 observations and 4 variables.
>   NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
>         real time           0.17 seconds
>         cpu time            0.14 seconds

I am looking for some help with this one. It'd be great if someone can explain what exactly is happening, what am I doing wrong and how to correct this error.

Thanks

Comment: Really?  Torrent Downloads?   At least pretend to be legit...

Comment: I am not proud of it but it is what it is

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the explanation in Ron Cody's book.  & means you need two spaces to separate varaibles; so you need a second space after the name (and other fields with &).

Wrong:

```
Roger Cody (908)782-1234 5ft. 10in. 50 1/8
```

Right:

```
Roger Cody  (908)782-1234 5ft. 10in.  50 1/8
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Joe, just didn't read the whole thing properly I guess

Comment: I wonder if you can help me with another SAS question, that'll save me from starting another thread. The question is I am using the input function to define a variable date as follows: date = input('13mar2000'd,date9.) when I run proc contents on the data set the length is shown as 8. Shouldn't it be 9?

Comment: You should start another question if you have another question - comments are not a good place (or an easy one) to answer. :)